# The instance member 'PageNumber' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Tags: class, flutter, oop, dart

The instance member 'PageNumber' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

How can I solve this?

Here is how it happens

The first class

```dart
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      int pageNumber = 1;
    
      Future<String> fetchPosts = FetchPosts(pageNumber).getPosts(); //<== The error happens here(PageNumber)
      List<wp.Post> posts = FetchPosts(pageNumber).posts;  //<== The error happens here (PageNumber)
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return buildPost(context, posts, index); //Building the posts list view
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Second class

```
    import 'package:flutter_wordpress/flutter_wordpress.dart' as wp;
    import 'package:saviortv/models/fetchWordPressPosts.dart';
    
    class FetchPosts {
      FetchPosts(this.pageNumber);
      final int pageNumber;
    
      List<wp.Post> posts = [];
    
      Future<String> getPosts() async {
        var res = await fetchPosts(pageNumber);
        print(pageNumber);
        posts = res;
        return "Success!";
      }
    }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [FutureBuilder](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9) in this scenario, as `getPosts()` is [asyc](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) method.

Refactored Code:

```
class FetchPosts {
  FetchPosts(this.pageNumber);
  final int pageNumber;

  Future<wp.Post> getPosts() async {
    List<wp.Post> posts = [];
    posts = await fetchPosts(pageNumber);
    print(pageNumber);
    return posts;
  }
}
```

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: FetchPosts(pageNumber).getPosts(),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if(snapshot.hasData){
           List<wp.Post> posts=snapshot.data;
           return ListView.builder(
             itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
             itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
               return buildPost(context, posts, index); //Building the posts list view
             },
           );
        }
         return Text('Error..');
       }
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to this.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      int pageNumber = 1;
      Future<String> fetchPosts;
      List<wp.Post> posts;

      @override
      void initState() {
        fetchPosts = FetchPosts(pageNumber).getPosts();
        posts = FetchPosts(pageNumber).posts;
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: posts == null ? 0 : posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return buildPost(context, posts, index); //Building the posts list view
          },
        );
      }
}
```

Comment: I want it to be in another file man... Can you give me a better solution?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by you want it to be in another file. Can you explain it?

Comment: I have separated the classes into two files (You can see in my question)  I seperated them so that I can use the other class in other files too